# Can you use Wygwam within Grid field?

Tags: wygwam

My question is pretty straight to the point.  I want to use WYGWAM as a data type within the Grid field, but it doesn't give me the option to select it?  Anyone know if this is possible?  I know it can be done within Matrix, but if I can just use the native Grid field, I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of March 12, 2014 ([Wygwam 3.3 release](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/changelog.html#wygwam-3-3)), Wygwam is compatible with Grid (you can Wygwam as a Grid cell type).

<strike>It looks like Wygwam is not compatible with Grid. The add-on page on [devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam) indicates no Grid compatibility and in a test I'm not able to do this with the latest versions of EE and Wygwam (2.7.3 and 3.2.2, respectively).</strike>

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can use expresso, it is compatibal with Grid.